# How to make overlay pane start at the top? (template10, UWP)

Tags: uwp, template10

i use template10 for my UWP-App and need to achive that overlay pane starts at the most top. Do you have any ideas if it is possible?

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAlTz.png)
[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUFZl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template 10, it is designed so that the `HamburgerButton` is separated away from the `SplitView`, you can refer to the source code of [HamburgerMenu.xaml](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Controls/HamburgerMenu.xaml). Take a blank Hamburger(Template 10) app's  `MainPage` for example, you can comment out the `controls:PageHeader` and modify the `controls:Resizer` like so:

```
<controls:Resizer x:Name="parameterResizer" Margin="16,16,16,0"
                  RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                  RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True">
```

This will solve part of this problem, but it only scratches the surface of a problem, when the window's size is resized or when it runs on mobile, because of its built-in, unexposed-to-the-project style of template 10, this method will fail to make the `HamburgerMenu` open from the start of the page.

If you're using `Template 10`, it's better to stick to use its `HamburgerMenu`, it will make the work easier. But if you insist to make it open from the start of the page, you can create your own [SplitView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which the `HamburgerButton` is inside of the `SplitView`, and together maybe your own navigation system for this.